# Can't create a new working MWAA environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

In the past two days, we can't create a new working MWAA environment. We started with Terraform - after apply, the environment is indicated as "Available" in the console, but when I click on the "Open UI" link, the UI never comes up. Then we manually created a couple environments, but with the same outcome. For us, MWAA as a service is practically down.

Here is what we are seeing when we click on "Open Airflow UI":

> **This page isn’t working**

> **zxxcvbnm-6666-4516-935b-bb9701f525e5-vpce.c20.us-west-2.airflow.amazonaws.com
> didn’t send any data.**
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Any insight/tip is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check service status in your region? On my side I have no issue with multiple MWAA environment in eu-west-1.

Answer (score 2):

So - it turns out some subnet combinations work, some don't. I believe it's a bug in MWAA.

Answer (score 1):

If the MWAA console (or AWS CLI) reports the environment as `AVAILABLE`, then Airflow is up and working.

The issue you're seeing is due to networking. From `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` I can tell that it is a message your browser is giving you based on the HTTP code/response it got from the URL. Unfortunately, these days most browsers engage in a sad trend of treating their users like idiots, and displaying overly vague and confusing error messages. What's actually happening is that your browser tries to access the Airflow URL, and fails, because AWS networking settings are not letting it through.

This may be due to:

- VPC configuration (particularly security groups and firewall rules). If you created the VPC using the MWAA wizard there shouldn't be a problem, but if you tweaked it or used your own VPC, there might be.
- MWAA configuration. There's a part in the `Networking` section where you must select public or private network - it will be much easier to get access if you select public.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that I just ran into when trying to create an MWAA environment is that the security group wasn't allowing HTTPS connections.

To adjust that:

1. Click into your environment to view the configuration and scroll down to the "Networking" section.
2. Click into "VPC security group(s)"
3. Click on the "Inbound Rules" tab
4. Click on the "Edit Inbound Rules" button
5. Click on the "Add Rule" button
6. In the "Type" dropdown, select "HTTPS"
7. Under the "Source" dropdown you will probably want "Custom" along with your desired CIDR block.
8. Click on "Save Rules", and your new rules should be applied.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! But that's not our case. We already have an inbound rule that allows HTTPS traffic.